# Viewshed calculation using SQL

Tags: raster, mapinfo, dem, sql-server, viewshed

Can i calculate viewshed in MS-SQL server? Viewshed analysis is Raster operation. I have elevation value vector observation as point vectors. Are there any methods to calculate Viewshed (using algorithm or something like that) ?

Answer (score 2):

This question is fairly broad, and so I am going to give a largely theoretical answer.

In short, there is not a MS SQL Server tool that would do this. However, it's still possible, if not easy. You can run a visibility analysis (viewshed) on any array of elevation values (aka raster) using an external script/algorithm.

Python libraries (e.g. NumPy) are able to work with numerical arrays. You could convert the points to an array (directly, if you have enough, or else interpolate to have a full elevation surface) and then do the math to look for visibility obstructions for each point in the array. This is not a particularly efficient way to do it, and it's easier to put the points into a GIS environment (or script with GIS tools) and work with them there.

An additional side note: viewshed accuracy improves as the elevation surface resolution improves. If you do not have many elevation observations, your results may not be accurate enough to be useful.